# DataGridView unique cell value c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a little problem with keeping values of cells in datagridview unique...
Let me explain: so, my database table consists of 2 attributes, ownerID (primary key) and ownerName...

let's say I have 3 entries in my DB:

```
    1 A
    2 B
    3 C
```

and when I delete B in my datagridview and update DB I'm left with:

```
    1 A
    3 C
```

and when I try to add new owner, let's say it's D, I want his ID to be 4, because it is primary key, but what I get is:

```
    1 A
    3 C
    3 D
```

So, I obviously need to keep my ownerID unique. I was using this line of code to do the job, but it's producing results above:

```
    private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            dataGridViewOwner.CurrentRow.SetValues(dataGridViewOwner.RowCount);
    }
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why not just have an `int` that increments whenever a new item is added?

Comment: tnx, that seems the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

To keep values of cells in datagridview unique
You should make unique values in database.
To do that:
1.ownerID should be IDENTITY in database
You can set it in table designer or
Script to create table   :

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YorTableName]
(
    [ownerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

```
[ownerName] [varchar](50) NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

1. Insert statement:
   Insert into YorTableName (ownerName) Values (@ownerName)
   Select @@Identity
   you insert only ownername , database creates unique value for ownerID and inserts it in the row Select  @@Identity retrives this unique value

3.Update the field ownerID in datagridviewer with the value returned from the DB

Answer (score 0):

```
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int max=0;
            for(int i=0;i<dataGridViewOwner.Rows.Count;i++)
              if(dataGridViewOwner.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value!=null && dataGridViewOwner.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value!=DBNull.Value )
              {
                  try
                   {
                         int pre= int.Parse(dataGridViewOwner.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        if(pre>max)
                              max=pre;
                   }
                  catch
                 {
                   }
              }//if
             max++;
            dataGridViewOwner.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value=max;//if assume crrent row is target new row
    }
```